# Invalid Firebase Registration Token

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, push-notification, firebase-console

Im trying to send push notifications with firebase, and i actually receive my token, but i cannot sent a simple message from the firebase console.

This is what my token looks like:
 `dRAlEiZYCSE:APA91bFfkyAi7qzzLoifd7x9WeayghNlpSchhCvYHCnqSVkOJpkWuDuWHxL9t2-nb_TN_1J6MyKBsfCHg7vbhCun`

i added this to my manifest file:

```
<service
            android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

And this here its from my firebaseInstanceIdService java file

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService{

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        MainActivity.tokenMain = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("test", FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
    }
}
```

I get the token, but when i try to use it in the console, i get `WRONG TOKEN FORMAT`

Comment: can you post the full log trace @martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my token was saved in varChar 100, which was simply too short. (token was cut off in the middle)

Answer (score 0):

It is stated  that a Firebase ID Token is different from a Custom Token, and that verifyIdToken() is not intended for verifying tokens generated with `generateCustomToken`().

legacy custom tokens still seem to work (signed with a database secret instead of a service account private key). Recommended is to generate and verify these yourself using firebase-token-generator.js and/or jsonwebtoken.js.

Copied from Firebase Project > Settings > Database > Secrets

Create custom database authentication tokens using a legacy Firebase token generator. There may be one secret that must exist at all times.